# Lucene TermQuery vs PhraseQuery : This filter query is enclosing a term query or phrase query?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a field, say F, which I keep un-analyzed by using KeywordTokenizer, Lowercase Filter and TrimFilter..

When I fire a filter query for F, the filter query is being parsed as a TermQuery rather than PhraseQuery..

Here is my filter query -

```
filter=F:"A B C"
```

Here is the code for what I am experimenting -

```
String fqs [] = msParams.getParams("fq");//msParams is ModifiableSolrParams
if(fqs != null) {
  for(int i=0; i<fqs.length; i++) {
    try {
      String field = null;
      QParser fqp = QParser.getParser(fqs[i], null, req);//req is request
      if(fqp.getQuery() instanceof TermQuery) {
        TermQuery fq = (TermQuery) fqp.getQuery();
        field = fq.getTerm().field();
```

My question is - Why does a query like `F:"A B C"` is being parsed by **solr** as TermQuery rather than PhraseQuery?

Comment: This looks like solr question more than a lucene one.... Could you share the query parser as it is configured inside the confix.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

After exploring the code found out what is happening -

If number of tokens are 1 (which is the case I have coz of KeywordTokenizer) the query above is parsed as TermQuery otherwise for more than 1 token, it looks for Boolean Query or Phrase Query..

Source File - SolrQueryParserBase.java Line 461 (Solr - 4.5.0)

```
   if (numTokens == 0)
      return null;
    else if (numTokens == 1) {
      try {
        boolean hasNext = buffer.incrementToken();
        assert hasNext == true;
        termAtt.fillBytesRef();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // safe to ignore, because we know the number of tokens
      }
      return newTermQuery(new Term(field, BytesRef.deepCopyOf(bytes)));
    } else {
      if (severalTokensAtSamePosition || (!quoted && !autoGeneratePhraseQueries)) {
        if (positionCount == 1 || (!quoted && !autoGeneratePhraseQueries)) {
          // no phrase query:
          BooleanQuery q = newBooleanQuery(positionCount == 1);

          BooleanClause.Occur occur = positionCount > 1 && operator == AND_OPERATOR ?
            BooleanClause.Occur.MUST : BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD;

          for (int i = 0; i < numTokens; i++) {
            try {
              boolean hasNext = buffer.incrementToken();
              assert hasNext == true;
              termAtt.fillBytesRef();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              // safe to ignore, because we know the number of tokens
            }
            Query currentQuery = newTermQuery(
                new Term(field, BytesRef.deepCopyOf(bytes)));
            q.add(currentQuery, occur);
          }
          return q;
        }
        else {
          // phrase query:
          MultiPhraseQuery mpq = newMultiPhraseQuery();
          mpq.setSlop(phraseSlop);
          List<Term> multiTerms = new ArrayList<Term>();
          int position = -1;
          for (int i = 0; i < numTokens; i++) {
            int positionIncrement = 1;
            try {
```